# Is there any way to disable autocomplete on Chrome or Safari

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete, safari

I'm using Opencart for my [ecommerce](http://seattle.homeenvoy.com) and point-of-sale website. Because we do point-of-sale (producing a quote/order for a customer on their behalf), I have to create customer profiles all the time. Username, password, etc.

I used `<form autocomplete="off">` on our customer account creation page, but it appears with the newest version of Chrome, autocomplete="off" is ignored, and so the customer's password is always defaulted to my admin password for the site. This is very annoying. Safari has the same issue.

Any way around this other than complete hacks?

Comment: You can disable chrome autofill/autocomplete in forms by using this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/29582380/4462191

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible to turn off autocomplete with a "--disable-ignore-autocomplete-off" flag (chrome 34).

Comment: Seemed to work for me - but I assume I'll need to instruct the other administrators of our site to do the same? Nothing that can be done on the web side?

Comment: Seems not, unfortunately.

Comment: Chrome ignores autocomplete='off' for password fields. This allows the password manager to give more power to users to manage their credentials on websites. It is the security team's view that this is very important for user security by allowing users to have unique and more complex passwords for websites.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution of this problem. It is not elegant but working. Usually browser's autocomplete tries to set saved password into a type="password" field and an email (or login) into the field before it. So you should change type of your password input to 'text'.

```
<input type="text" name"password" id="password_input" />
```

And then change it back to 'password' with Javascript

```
setTimeout(function (){
    $('#password_input').attr('type', 'password');
}, 500);
```

Without timeout it won't work in Safari.